# Not Using Full Screen on Raspberry PI 3

Tags: display-resolution

Just installed Ubuntu on a Raspberry PI 3. Somehow it does not use the full screen, there is a black 20~30 pixels-wide band all around (top/bottom and left/right).

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search ----

Disable overscan

Edit the boot/config.txt file to make the change:

```
   sudo nano /boot/config.txt
      Change this line:
          #disable_overscan=1
                  to:
          disable_overscan=1
```

Then, save the file and exit.

Reboot your Pi

Comment: Thank you. I did a google search for 'ubuntu not using full screen' and all I found was related to a Virtual machine ... maybe I did not use the correct terminology.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed it's a little different in 18.04+

Add `disable_overscan=1` to the `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` file.

Then reboot.